# Bubble sort works for small list sizes and not for big entries

Tags: java, generics

I programmed a Abstract sorter with several methods that implements a SORTER interface.

sorter interface
 `<T> void sort(@NotNull final Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull final List<T> list);`

AbstractSorter

```
public abstract class AbstractSorter implements Sorter, ObservableSorter{

private SorterType type;
protected List<SorterListener> listeners;

protected AbstractSorter(SorterType type) {
    this.type = type;
    listeners = new LinkedList<>();
}

protected <T> boolean greater(@NotNull List<T> list, int i, int j, @NotNull Comparator<T> comp) {
    listeners.forEach(e -> e.greater(0,0));
    return comp.compare(list.get(i),list.get(j)) > 0;
}

protected <T> void swap(@NotNull List<T> list, int i, int j){
    T aux = list.get(i);
    list.set(i, list.get(j));
    list.set(j, aux);
    /*Updates Observers*/
    listeners.stream().forEach(e -> e.swap(i,j));
}
protected <T> void compSwap(@NotNull List<T> list, int i, int j,@NotNull Comparator<T> comp){
    if(greater(list,i,j,comp))swap(list, i,j);
}
public abstract <T> void sort(@NotNull Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull List<T> list );

@NotNull
public SorterType getType() {
    return type;
}

@Override
public void addSorterListener(@NotNull SorterListener sorterListener) {listeners.add(sorterListener);}

@Override
public void removeSorterListener(@NotNull SorterListener sorterListener) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if(!listeners.contains(sorterListener)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Listener not found");
    listeners.remove(sorterListener);
}
```

}

And finally my bubblesort

```
public class BubbleSort extends AbstractSorter{

public BubbleSort() {super(SorterType.BUBBLE);}

@Override
public <T> void sort(@NotNull Comparator<T> comparator, @NotNull List<T> list) {

    /*Updates Observers*/
    listeners.stream().forEach(e-> e.box(0, list.size()));

    System.out.println(list.size());
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int size = list.size();
    while(swapped){
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - j ; i++) {
            if(greater(list,i,i+1,comparator)){
                swap(list,i,i+1);
                System.out.println(i + " " + (i+1));
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The thing is, when i test my bubble sort for up to 1000 elements it works properly, but when i put a list of 5000 elements it takes a lot of time (ike 10 mins or more) to finish the task, an i cannot understand why.

Comment: Is your input `List` a `ArrayList`?
If not your greater method is O(n).

Comment: Yes, it is an array list. I have an integer Data set generator, that produces an ascendingList (array list of a for from 1 to 5000) a decendingList and a random list, with math.random

Comment: Maybe the problem is that BubbleSort is O(n^2) anyway.

Comment: How do you measure the performance? And how many times do you run the test? Keep in mind that the JVM recompiles your code several times to optimize it.

Comment: I cant understand why it takes so long, this is a wotk i have to hand in, and many of my class mates solve entries of 5000 elements within seconds for every sorter, and i tested this code in several computers and the time is yet the same

Comment: Show us the initialization and the code of your `Listener`. Without them your code runs fast.